# How to make people and company search in linkedIn oauth2

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

Have a good day programmers.

### Question :

I just want to know is that possible to search people(by first-name,last-name) in linkedIn oauth2 .Im using this(/v1/people/~:(firstName,lastName) code to find my own profile name and it's working fine, got it from [here](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/code-samples). But if I try to `make people/company search` it show me error.I google'd but didn't find any relevant answer. and one more question how to make this search query in oauth2 any sample code or reference or document is really helpfull.

**My Code**

```
$user2 = fetch('GET', '/v1/people-search::(~,id,first-name=kamesh,last-name=waran):(id,first-name,last-name,educations)');
```

---

```
function fetch(){
$params = array('oauth2_access_token' => $_SESSION['access_token'],
'format' => 'json'
);
$url = 'https://api.linkedin.com' . $resource . '?' . http_build_query($params);
$context = stream_context_create(
array('http' =>
array('method' => $method,
)
)
);

$response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

return json_decode($response);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution :** After a long search i found people search/company search is only possible with vetted API. I uploated the same question in  [LinkedIN forum](https://developer.linkedin.com/forum/unable-make-people-and-company-search-linked-oauth2) and got the answer.

**More Info :** [Click here to apply vetted API](https://developers.linkedin.com/documents/people-search-api)